# How can I select & filtering using webdriverio.react$$

Tags: webdriver-io

I am new webdriverio and react.
I am learning a look at the official documentation the following.
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/react$$.html

```
it('should calculate 7 * 6', () => {
    browser.url('https://ahfarmer.github.io/calculator/');

    const orangeButtons = browser.react$$('t', {
        props: { orange: true }
    })
    console.log(orangeButtons.map((btn) => btn.getText())); // prints "[ '÷', 'x', '-', '+', '=' ]"
});
```

But I could not understand the selector of 't'.
What is the 't'?

It seems that there is no 't' tag in target html.
https://ahfarmer.github.io/calculator/

Also I tried to select orange buttons as the following.

```
console.log(browser.react$$('Button',{
  props: { orange: true }
}).map((obj) => obj.getText()));
```

But it was not worked.

How can I select using tag name "Button"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it myself.

Because it's getting minified.

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/239